# react insert inside of string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, replace

```
var result = "I am a dog";
var searchterm = "a";
```

How do I insert "(" before every "a" and ")" after every "a" so the new result is

```
newresult = "I (a)m (a) dog"
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [replaceAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method.

```js
var result = "I am a dog";
var searchterm = "a";

const output = result.replaceAll(searchterm, `(${searchterm})`);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: apprve the answer would be appreciated if it's helpful @Ariel

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result = "I am a samovar";

const searchTerms = [" am ", " a "];
const replacements = [" (a)m ", " (a) "];

searchTerms.map((term, i) => { 
    result = result.replaceAll(term, replacements[i]) 
})

console.log(result)
```